# How to resolve __gcov_init undefined reference issue when linking

Tags: linker, undefined-reference, gcov

I now work on C code coverage study and encountered following issue, GCC version 4.4.6:

1. Added compiler flag `CFLAGS = --coverage` and linker option `LDFLAGS := --coverage` or `LOCAL_LDLIBS := --coverage` and got the error:

`undefined reference to '__gcov_init'" and "undefined reference to '__gcov_merge_add'`

2. Added option `LOCAL_LDFLAGS := --coverage`, and got link error:

`libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function __gcov_set_sampling_rate: undefined reference to '__gcov_sampling_rate' 
libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function gcov_exit: undefined reference to '__gcov_pmu_profile_filename' 
libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function __gcov_init: undefined reference to '__gcov_pmu_profile_options' '__gcov_pmu_top_n_address'`

Can anyone help to provide some suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 77):

Try this approach:

Compile the code for which you want to generate the coverage with these options:

`CFLAGS: -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`

`LFLAGS: -lgcov --coverage`

If this doesn't solve the problem, then please provide some information on the structure of your application, i.e. whether its single program or an application involving shared/static libraries etc.

Comment: For me adding --coverage to LFLAGS solved the issue.
Earlier I was using only -lgcov for LFLAGS.

Comment: I believe adding `--coverage` to `LFLAGS` is only necessary for the LLVM compiler on Mac.

Comment: Add -lgcov before -lc in the LFLAGS

Answer (score 17):

Are you linking with `-lgcov`?

If you are using a Makefile it would be of great help to have a look at it in order to help you.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried -lgcov link option but still encountered above issue 1). Thanks for your reply

Comment: That was what I missed. Thanks! It worked.

Comment: Perfect! I had a custom bash build script with `gcc ${OBJECT_FILES[@]} -o "$BUILD_DIR/$PROGRAM_NAME"` in it for the linking portion of the build. Simply adding `-lgcov` like this made it work!: `gcc ${OBJECT_FILES[@]} -lgcov -o "$BUILD_DIR/$PROGRAM_NAME"`.

Answer (score 5):

you have to provide LDFLAGS to resolve this issue.

```
LDFLAGS += " -lgcov --coverage"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure which change finally did the trick for me but I think it was the `-fprofile-generate` flag. Using GNAT GPS I went to the `Switches` tab on the left and then selected the `Ada Linker` tab on the top. Then I enabled the checkbox for `Code Coverage`. Oh yeah I've found that on the `Builder` tab in that same area if you enable the `Recompile if switches changed` checkbox it can save a lot of teeth-gnashing. Probably slows things down for the pros but I found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to put the '-lgcov' to the right of the object being profiled instead of in Flags. Something like.
gcc -pg -o myprog myprog.o -lgmp.a -lgcov

Answer (score 1):

I had undefined reference to gcov functions (`undefined reference to '__gcov_exit'`) while I tried to enable coverage on a C project using a C++ test harness (CppUTest). Build system was handled by CMake.

Compilers and gcov were aligned on the same version (`gcc --version`, `g++ --version` and `gcov --version` gave the same version) but it seems that my build system was previously configured to use gcc 5 while g++ 8 and gcov 8 were used (resulting to an additional included directory by the linker: usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5). **I cleaned the build tree and generated it again thanks to CMake which fixed the error.**

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue too and as most of the answers above indicated it needed us to add lcov/gcov libraries at the time of linking.
We are using cmake and in CmakeLists.txt file we were missing

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE gcov)
```

This was needed of course in addition to the build flag "--coverage"
(Pls note we can either use "--coverage" or "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" separately)