# Can glibc use the gcov to test the code coverage?

Tags: build, glibc, gcov

I want to test code coverage of one glibc source code file(such as dl-load.c) use gcov, can it happen? and how to do it?

I refered to this:
[How to resolve __gcov_init undefined reference issue when linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682606/how-to-resolve-gcov-init-undefined-reference-issue-when-linking)

and try to make, found the build errors:
/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/10.3.1/libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function `gcov_write_block': GNU-toolchain/arm-10/src/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/gcov-io.c:268: undefined reference to` fwrite'
../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/10.3.1/libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function `gcov_read_words': arm-10/src/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/gcov-io.c:491: undefined reference to` fread'
....
....