# How to use GCC-11 -fprofile-use option

Tags: gcc, optimization

After reading the documentation for GCC-11, I'm trying to understand how to use `-fprofile-use`, which requires requires to generate profiling information. The thing is that the documentation describes all the available flags but with no examples. A Google search didn't return any particularly specific information so I'm wondering if anyone is aware of an example (describing how to use GCC profiling) or is familiar with it. The code that I'm working with has lots of double-precision operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What information does GCC Profile Guided Optimization (PGO) collect and which optimizations use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881292/what-information-does-gcc-profile-guided-optimization-pgo-collect-and-which-op)

Comment: Thanks. The other thread is asking a very similar question to mine. In addition to pointing to a book (almost 15 years old) that describes the theoretical background (it looks interesting but obviously I haven't had time to read it), it lists 3 steps. It's not exactly an example as I was looking for, but it provides a starting point.